# Evaluate section by button click

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I have a section in my notebook devoted to unit testing, since I'm not comfortable to use the built-in system. I'd like to evaluate the entire section by button click. But I get lost in the notebook FrontEnd and what not evaluation and selection controls. All I achieved so far is to create the `Button[]` (yay!).

In short:

-The section is introduced by the 3rd [Alt+3]-headline
-The entire section group should be evaluated
-The button can pretty much be located anywhere, specifically inside this section, if it makes the code easier

I am aware that I can click the grouping brace at the right and then Shift+Enter, but it requires some maneuvering skills to not misclick and accidentally evaluate only half or the entire notebook.

Comment: Try: Button["Evaluate selected cell", 
 SelectionEvaluate[SelectedNotebook[]]]

Comment: I don't want to evaluate the selected cell but the group the selected cell is in

Comment: I have button in my notebook toolbar (aka docked cell) that runs all unit tests that reside in a *separate* .wlt file. This is just a text file with many `VerificationTest` commands. This way it runs quite fast compared to testing notebooks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does it fit your needs?

It can be anywhere in the notebook with your tests:

```
Button[
 "Run 3rd subchapter's group"
, SelectionMove[
    Cells[CellStyle -> "Subchapter"][[3]]
  , All
  , CellGroup
  ]
; SelectionEvaluate @ EvaluationNotebook[]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's "Chapter", not "Subchapter" in my Notebook (Version 12.1) but otherwise this works fine :)

Comment: Does menu Format > Style list "Chapter" next to Alt+3 for you?

Comment: Yes, that's how I found the correct Identifier.