# Can I use Button to issue a ctrl-enter command?

Tags: button

I'd like to click Button to activate a particular cell the same as if I'd typed ctrl-enter on the keyboard. So far, I can't get Button to do much. It will do something simple like Print a string, but on any more complex commands it always fails.

Comment: Similar to [230613](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230613/evaluate-section-by-button-click).

Answer (score 2):

You may put: "SelectionEvaluate" inside a button to evaluate the current selection. E.g:

```
Button["click", SelectionEvaluate@EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

This will create a button. If you now select a cell or a piece of code and click the button, the selected piece will be evaluated. E.g.

If you write

```
1+1
```

and select it and then click the button, 1+1 will be replaced by 2.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Except I have to keep Selecting the cell I want to activate again, when I was hoping Button could repeatedly activate a particular named cell without stopping to select it, like a HTML button. Should be simple, but it's not. I want to generate random images to examine and pick out the ones I like without constantly re-selecting. Should be a simple thing to do, but I can't get it working.

Comment: I thought this would work but Button defeats me at every turn: 
Button["Print Hello", Evaluate[Print["Hello, World!"]]]